# How can I compose a pair of functions in C++?

Tags: c++

Let `f` and `g` be two one-argument functions. The composition `f` after `g` is defined to be the function `x \mapsto f(g(x))`.

Say the  procedure `compose` implements composition. As an example, if `inc` is a procedure that adds 1 to its argument and `square` squares its argument,
`((compose square inc) 6)`
evaluates to 49.

The solution is straightforward. It looks very much like its mathematical analogue:

```
(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
Let's test:
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (inc x) (+ x 1))

((compose square inc) 6)
Output:
 49
```

How can I implement composition using C++ ? Is it possible to write the arguments like that and have the function implement itself?

Comment: Have a look at [c++ lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: As for your question title, I'm pretty sure it is possible. There are rarely patterns that can't be implemented in c++.

Comment: thank you. I found your link useful.. i think people hate that question so that i might delete it . but thank you !

Comment: [auto lambdas are your friend](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11450c085f3f1ece)

Comment: yeah thank you a lot for that, please put it as an answer to close it !

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. May you need to do some work to reach the goal? Yes. Sorry, but I really hate these obvious "can it be done' questions. The answer is always in 99.999pct of the case " yes, of course, if you just know how".

Comment: @E.Hamed I've edited your question in an attempt to improve the clarity and (hopefully) the question quality. If you disagree that the question has been improved or think that it now deviates from your original intent, either you can ask me to roll it back, or do so yourself.

Comment: jaggedSpire, it's great, thank you, and sorry for not clarifying my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with very much similar syntax:

```
auto compose = [](auto f, auto g){
    return [f,g](auto x){return f(g(x));};
};

auto square = [](auto i){return i * i;};

auto inc = [](auto i){return i + 1;};

compose(square, inc)(6); // result is 49
```

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11450c085f3f1ece)

The `[](auto arg){}` is a *generic lambda*, and you may read more about them (and non-generic lambdas) on [cppreference's page on lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Unlike lambdas with a specified argument type (`[](int arg){}`), they act like a functor with a templated `operator()`, and thus allow their argument type to be deduced where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple implementation:

```
template <class F, class G, class T>
auto compose(F f, G g, T x)
{
  return f(g(x));
}
```

Usage:

```
auto foo(int x)
{
  return x + 1;
}

auto bar(int x)
{
  return x * 2;
}

auto test()
{
  return compose(foo, bar, 24);
}
```

It can be optimized to move the argument.

---

If you want a lambda for `foo` and `bar` specifically:

```
auto compose = [](auto x) { return foo(bar(x)); }
```

and then:

```
cout << compose(24);
```